# How to encrypt all MongoDB fields in document with Spring framework

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, encryption

I am using Spring framework with mongoDB, so the question is how to encrypt all my documents and store them encrypted. For now there is no encryption and all the documents are stored in original form. So how to implement encryption (for example AES)

User password is encrypted in MD5, but I want to encrypt messages that this user gets

P.S [This plugin doesn't work with Spring 2.0+](https://github.com/bolcom/spring-data-mongodb-encrypt)

[Current mongo database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqFKl.png)

Thank you

Comment: The link you provided for the plugin now is compatible with spring 2.0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MongoDB enterprise version. it is supporting encryption. Itz encryption solution that protects your data, both in-flight and at-rest.
If you don't have enterprise version you should do disk level encryption.
Otherwise you should encrypt data in application side and send it in to MongoDB.